# Odds of summation of ten dice roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I flip 10 dice, what's the probability I get an Odd sum??
I couldn't do anything with this any help would be really appreciated...

Comment: $\frac12{}{}{}$.

Comment: why ?? can you explain plz?

Comment: If you flip 9 dice and you have either odd or even sum what's the probability to get odd sum if you flip the 10th dice?

Comment: oops ... thanks